# How do I update/delete objects inside this.state array in React

Tags: reactjs

So I have a React component where I have:

```
getInitialState: function () {
    return {
        peopleDetails: []
    }
}
```

`peopleDetails` will contain objects which will have property names like name, email, phone etc.

Here's the problem: I'll be passing methods to child components which should mutate the objects of this array. Some methods will just edit a person's email, another will edit the phone etc. Thus, they'll need to call `setState`.

As far as I understand, `setState` should return a new copy of the object. I find this impossible to do because things are difficult enough even if I have to mutate the object (I'll have to specify some filters to find it inside an array, then change its value etc).

I'm pretty sure a lot of React apps use data structures like these...where in the state you have an array holding objects and you'll need to do stuff to those objects. Is there some easy way to accomplish this, respecting the "rule" that each `setState` invocation should return a completely new state object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really don't want to use immutable data, then you can directly mutate the properties you like and invoke a `this.forceUpdate()` instead of `setState` after mutations have occurred.

If you were to proceed with immutable data, then adding to that array would return a new array containing the new object. If you removed that person, you'd then return a new empty array. If you were to modify an item in-place in the array, then you'd build a new array using concat/slice to get all elements that haven't changed, then add your changed element, then add everything after the changed element's index.

For a more in-depth discussion on avoiding array mutations, check out [this talk](https://egghead.io/lessons/javascript-redux-avoiding-array-mutations-with-concat-slice-and-spread).